# Getting Text from ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a ComboBox in WPF and I cant access its selected item text.

I have tried

```
cbItem.Text;
cbItem.SelectedItem.ToString();
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="cbItem" SelectedValuePath="ITEM_ID">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding ITEM_NAME}" />
          </DataTemplate>
     </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: ((ComboBoxItem)cbItem.SelectedItem).Content.ToString() would work in Silverlight if memory serves - might work in WPF but not sure

Comment: I get all types of casting errors using this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do `ITEM_ID` and `ITEM_NAME` come from an object?

```
String textComboBox = ((ITEMCLASS)cbItem.SelectedItem).ITEM_NAME.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 cbItem.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

*This will work only if combobox values are same as the combobox text*

**EDIT:**

**Solution 1**

You have to get access to the ComboBox's TextBox:

```
var str = (TextBox)cbItem.Template.FindName("PART_EditableTextBox", cbItem);
```

Then you can access the SelectedText property of that TextBox:

```
var selectedText = str.SelectedText; // This will give you text of selected item
```

**Solution 2**

```
ComboBoxItem typeItem = (ComboBoxItem)cbItem.SelectedItem;

string value = typeItem.Content.ToString();// This will give you text of selected item
```

Comment: That just returns the ITEM_ID

Comment: I really wanted to use solution 2 but Im getting casting errors. The combobox is bound to an entity framework table not sure if that has anything to do with it.

Comment: Can you tell us what error you are getting after applying solution 2? What about solution 1?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.item_0381CED50C771CCCBA64F1663BFA5D04CD83081D7B3131F059392F360735FBED' to type 'System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem'.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<ComboBox Name="cbItem" SelectedValuePath="ITEM_ID">
 <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Name="txtblck" Text="{Binding ITEM_NAME}" />
      </DataTemplate>
 </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
```

```
TextBox str = (TextBox)cbItem.FindName("txtblck");

string text = str.Text;
```